# Can you use <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects> Element for 64-bit UWP Apps?

Tags: uwp

Can you use gcAllowVeryLargeObjects for UWP apps.  Is it even needed?

I tried to stick following XML in the Default.rd.xml file but it didn't like it there.

```
<configuration>  
  <runtime>  
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />  
  </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried a test with a 3,809,476,608 byte file through my 64-bit UWP App and it worked fine without gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled.  Also did a 4,193,052,256 byte file with no problem.  It didn't like my 7.1 GB file but that was expected since beyond array and 'uint' MaxValue of 4,294,967,295 bytes.

Those IBuffers just scale up to size needed with no work on my part.  Nice!

Using MS .Net Framework Version 4.7.02046